# Динамический двумерный массив строк char

Tags: char, массивы, c, c++

Добрый день! Пытаюсь реализовать данное задание:

```
Ввести n послідовностей стрингових констант різної довжини. Вирівняти їх у відповідності з довжиною найбільш короткої. Представити їх у вигляді символьної матриці. Виконати установку заданих елементів матриці у задане значення.
```

На сколько я понял, нужно просто отсортировать массив (двумерный) строк, так, что бы первая строка была наименьшей длинны. А дальше просто вывести посимвпольно.

Вот код, но у меня не получается вывести массив. Хотя возможно тут гораздо больше ошибок, чем я думаю, VS2013 говорит только про то, что вывод в конце не верный (походу, куда то в памяти не туда залажу).
Как правильно сделать, прошу помочь сообщество!

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int compare(const void *, const void *); // это прототип ф-ии, он нужен что бы не писать всю ф-ию выше main'а, при этом видеть что за ф-ия у тебя и какие в ней аргументы {ее описание ниже, после main}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int n; // кол-во строк
    cout << "input amount of strings ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Введите " << n << " размеров для каждой строки: " << endl;
    int *symb = new int[n]; // массив для хранения длины каждой новой строки для массива строк
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> symb[i];

    char **str_mas = new char *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        str_mas[i] = new char [symb[i]+1];

    /*for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)  { // вводим строки для твоего массива двумерного char
        cout << "Введите строку номер " << i + 1 << ": ";
        for (int j = 0; j < symb[i]; j++)
            cin >> str_mas[i][j];
    }*/

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "Введите строку номер " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin.getline(str_mas[i], symb[i]+1);
    }

    char **new_str_mas = new char*[n]; // в этот массив копируем строки из первого в порядке возрастания длины строк
    for (int i =0; i < n; ++i)
        new_str_mas[i] = new char[symb[i]];

    memset(new_str_mas, 0, sizeof(new_str_mas)); // ф-ия для очистки массива char от мусора

    qsort(symb, n, sizeof(int), compare); // ф-ия сортировки, нужна что бы был массив с размерами каждой строки char отсортирован, дальше нужен для пермещения строки из старого массива строк в новый

    //strlen() - происходит проверку строки с соответствующим размером из массива, где
    // хранятся размеры строк, и если размер совпал - копирование в новый массив строк
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (strlen(str_mas[j]) == symb[i]) {
            strcpy_s(new_str_mas[j], strlen(str_mas[i]), str_mas[i]);
        }
    }

        // НУЖЕН ВЫВОД
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < symb[i]; ++j) {
        cout << new_str_mas[i][j];
        if (j == symb[i] - 1) 
            cout << endl;
    }

    _getch();
}

// эта ф-ия вспомогательная для стандартной ф-ии сортировки qsort(см.выше), без нее qsort doesnt work!
int compare(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Извините, но какой-то бред. Судя по заданию (которое, кст., на украинском языке, а поэтому я мог что-то не так понять, тогда - *извините*) Вам нужно было ввести несколько строк разной длины, затем выровнять эти строки относительно строки меньшей длинны - тогда: если создание нового символьного массива принципиально - копируйте из исходного массива в новый (который, кстати, будет иметь размерность `n x длину_самой_короткой_строки`), тогда полностью скопируется только самая короткая строка, остальные обрежуться - и, выводите );
если не принципиально - выводите на консоль символы из исходного массива, но не более `длину_самой_короткой_строки` символов )